# How to get bar index on specific date

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am new to pine script.
I want to compare the prices on 2 specific date.

But how would I get the bar_index on a particular date?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timestamp function would return UNIX time of specified date and time.

If time in ms is more the Jan 3, grab the low.
For intraday specify minutes in the timestamp function.

```
//@version=4
study("low on specific date")

specificDate = time >= timestamp(2019, 1, 3, 00, 00)

var float lowOnDate= na
if specificDate and not specificDate[1]
    lowOnDate := low
plot(lowOnDate)
```

Comment: I wish to grab the day low value of certain date say 3 Jan 2019.  is it the best way?  I dont need intraday value.  Anyway to simplify the code so that I dont need to input 4 Jan 2019?

Comment: Edited the answer. Now script grab the low value if the date is reached.

Answer (score 5):

Get bar index at specific date across all time frames.

```
  //@version=5

  anchorTime = input.time(timestamp("20 May 2022 15:00 -0500"), "Date")

  anchorBarIndex = (time - anchorTime) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))

  anchorBarsBack = bar_index - anchorBarIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to get candle data in 1H timeframe on June 30th 3AM GMT+8

`x1 = (time - timestamp("GMT+8",2021,06,30,03,00,00))/3600000`

`candleHigh = high[x1]`

If you're in different TF just convert it to milisecond