# How to get bar_index value on specific date

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to find the `bar_index` for each time, when I select the time interactively on a specific timeframe.

lets say in `1D` timeframe I select the today date via

`i_date = input.time(timestamp("23 Aug 2023 00:00 +0300"), "Date", confirm=true)`

Then I expect that the corresponding  `bar_index` be `0` for it.
In the same way, for the time of yesterday, I expect that `bar_index` be `1`.
How can I do this?

I also looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025721/how-to-get-bar-index-on-specific-date) but it is not computing the bar index as I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `(time == i_date)` is `true` and store the `bar_index` in a `var`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

i_date = input.time(timestamp("23 Aug 2023 00:00 +0300"), "Date", confirm=true)

var int idx_date = na

idx_date := (time == i_date) ? bar_index : idx_date

plotchar(idx_date, "Idx", "")
plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "")
```

Here, I selected yesterday as the input. The `bar_index` in the image points to today. So, `idx_date` is `today - 1`.
[image]

Comment: Great, the final answer is basically `str.tostring(bar_index-idx_date)`, thanks. 
Just out of curiosity, how you are showing the results on the right side in the `My Script` side bar on the right?

Comment: All the plots will be there by default. It is called "Data Window". Right below the "Alerts" button.